# using axlsx gem how to generate excel in landscape orientation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I am using `axlsx` gem in rails and need to generate excel in landscape orientation

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Semestre") do |sheet|
sheet.add_row ["Período", "Turma", "Sala", "Disciplina", "Tipo", "Híbrida", "Dia da Semana", "Hora Inicial", "Hora Final", "CH", "Curso", "Professor", "Matrícula"]

  @oferta.each do |oferta|

if oferta.sala_id != nil 
  sala=oferta.sala.nome 
else 
  sala="-" 
end
sheet.add_row [oferta.periodo, oferta.codturma, sala, oferta.disciplinaturma.disciplina.nome, oferta.tipoaula, oferta.disciplinaturma.disciplina.hibrida, oferta.diasemana, oferta.horainicial.try(:strftime, ("%H:%M")), oferta.horafinal.try(:strftime, ("%H:%M")), oferta.cargahoraria.to_s+" h", oferta.disciplinaturma.turma.curso.nome, oferta.professor.nome, oferta.professor.matricula]
```

end
end

Comment: I formatted the question, however, there no really question, please improve the question to be more exact in showing what you are asking about.

Comment: Did [searching Github](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/search?q=orientation) not turn up any good results?

Comment: @praveen has the correct answer below. I can tell you are using axlsx_rails, which is why you have axlsx_package. You can still use the page setup when you add the worksheet with `wb.add_worksheet`. See this example: [Docs](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb#L610)

Comment: As an aside one does not generate excel in landscape orientation. A spreadsheet does not have an orientation but you can set the default print orientation (e.g. page scale and margins) as specified below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked this [document](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Worksheet)

wb = Axlsx::Package.new.workbook

## using options when creating the worksheet.

ws = wb.add_worksheet :page_setup => {:fit_to_width => 2, :orientation => :landscape}

This [doc](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb) also help you